# SAS Forecast Studio code download

Tags: sas

SAS Forecast Studio is a programming tool that is used for business intelligence forecasting.  It (presumably) generates SAS code on the back end that then produces the output.

Is there any way to get access to the generated SAS code that was used to produce the output, and save it as a .SAS file, a program in the project, or to the clipboard?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed, except that it was probably closed by non-SAS users.  It's a perfectly clear question to a SAS user.

Comment: I don't have any familiarity with Forecast Studio; perhaps Dom does, or one of the other users.  You also might post on communities.sas.com - you're more likely to find someone there with this specific knowledge I suspect.

Comment: If FS is anything like EM then yes you can.  If you've purchased the software I'd just contact SAS tech support - its one of the reasons you pay millions for the software.

Comment: thank you... even I am surprised why did the moderators find the questions unclear ! I will definitely post on SAS communities.

Comment: @userNid Anyone with 3000 reputation or higher can vote to close; moderators rarely do so.  In this case it was probably unclear because it doesn't "look" like a good programming question.  You probably could have asked it with a bit more detail to make it clear that it was a valid question, ie, explained a tiny bit about what Forecast Studio is and what you mean by translate to SAS program, but to me it's fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I hope it can be useful for someone;
The SAS code is available from the Forecast Studio.

Access your project, click "Project" in the menu bar and select "SAS Code..."